# Jest + Enzyme testing error in mapStateToProps()

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a problem when I'm testing redux using enzymes `mount` function.

`Error: Uncaught [TypeError: selectors.selectMessages is not a function]`

Why do I get this error ?

```js
//badgeSelector.js. R - is Ramda.

import { createSelector } from 'reselect'
export const selectMessages = createSelector(R.path(['badgeReducer', 'unreadMessages']), (messages) => messages)

//App.js
import * as selectors from 'commons/selectors/badgeSelector'

export class App extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            ...
        )
    }
}

export default connect(
        (state) => ({
            messages: selectors.selectMessages(state)
        }),
        (dispatch) => ({
            updateBadge: () => {
                dispatch(updateBadge())
            }
        })
    )(App)
    
//App.test.js

import ConnectedApp, {App} from './App'

describe('Badge react-redux test mount: ', () => {
        const mockStore = configureStore()
        let store, wrapper
        beforeEach(() => {
            store = mockStore(state)
            wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><ConnectedApp /></Provider>) //Error when mount
        })

        it('render mount component', () => {
            expect(wrapper.find(ConnectedApp).length).toEqual(1)
        })
    })
```

Comment: How are you exporting your selectors from `commons/selectors/badgeSelector` ? Are you bundling all your methods into a single (default?) object? Or are you exporting as individual functions?

Comment: `selectMessages` is probably not being exported correctly, we need to see what the content of `selectors` is to solve this.

Comment: @DacreDenny individual functions `export const selectMessages = createSelector(R.path(['badgeReducer', 'unreadMessages']), (messages) => messages)`

Comment: @rymdmaskin commented above

Comment: And you're importing createSelector like so? `import { createSelector } from 'reselect'`

Comment: @DacreDenny yes, like this

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you replace `selectMessages` like so? `const selectMessages = () => { console.log('i got called'); return []; }`. Does it compile and run? And if so, do you see the message in your console?

Comment: @DacreDenny yes, but in result of this select will be a function

`Expected value to equal:
  "Number"
Received:
  "Function"`

Or `Received: "Array"` if `return []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: jest not accept alias paths from webpack

To fix above bug you need to setup alias if needed:

```js
alias: {
            component: path.resolve(__dirname, './main/component'),
            commons: path.resolve(__dirname, './main/app/src/common')
        }
```

And correctly setup jest moduleNameMapper:

```js
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "^commons(.*)$": "<rootDir>/main/app/src/common/$1",
      "^component(.*)$": "<rootDir>/main/component/$1"
    }
```